# Cosine Similarity Kernel for SVM

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, cosine-similarity, kernel-density

So I've been working on this chatbot project, I'm using SVM for its ML and I really want to use cosine similarity as kernel. i've tried using pykernel ([as suggested from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468368/custom-kernels-for-svm-when-to-apply-them)) or another code from different source, but it's still not working, and I don't know why...

say that i have `train.py` code like this

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import numpy as np
import pickle, csv, json, timeit, random, os, nltk
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split as tts
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder as LE
from Sastrawi.Stemmer.StemmerFactory import StemmerFactory
from Sastrawi.StopWordRemover.StopWordRemoverFactory import StopWordRemoverFactory
import my_kernel

def preprocessing(text):
    factory1 = StopWordRemoverFactory()
    StopWord = factory1.create_stop_word_remover()
    text = StopWord.remove(text)
    factory2 = StemmerFactory()
    stemmer = factory2.create_stemmer()
    return (stemmer.stem(text))

le = LE()
tfv = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1)

file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),"scraping","tes.json")
svm_pickle_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),"data","svm_model.pickle")

if os.path.exists(svm_pickle_path):
    os.remove(svm_pickle_path)

tit = [] # Title
cat = [] # Category
post = [] # Post

with open(file, "r") as sentences_file:
    reader = json.load(sentences_file)
    for row in reader:
        tit.append(preprocessing(row["Judul"]))
        cat.append(preprocessing(row["Kategori"]))
        post.append(preprocessing(row["Post"]))

tfv.fit(tit)
le.fit(cat)

features = tfv.transform(tit)
labels = le.transform(cat)

trainx, testx, trainy, testy = tts(features, labels, test_size=.30, random_state=42)

model = SVC(kernel=my_kernel, C=1.5)

f = open(svm_pickle_path, 'wb')
pickle.dump(model.fit(trainx, trainy), f)
f.close()

print("SVC training score:", model.score(testx, testy))

with open(svm_pickle_path, 'rb') as file:  
    pickle_model = pickle.load(file)

score = pickle_model.score(testx, testy)  
print("Test score: {0:.2f} %".format(100 * score))  
Ypredict = pickle_model.predict(testx)
print(Ypredict)
```

and for `my_kernel.py` code :

```
import numpy as np
import math
from numpy import linalg as LA

def my_kernel(X, Y):
    norm = LA.norm(X) * LA.norm(Y)
    return np.dot(X, Y.T)/norm
```

and it shows this everytime I run the program

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "F:\env\chatbot\chatbotProj\chatbotProj\train.py", line 84, in <module>
pickle.dump(model.fit(trainx, trainy), f)

File "F:\env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 212, in fit
fit(X, y, sample_weight, solver_type, kernel, random_seed=seed)

File "F:\env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 252, in _dense_fit
X = self._compute_kernel(X)

File "F:\env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 380, in _compute_kernel
kernel = self.kernel(X, self.__Xfit)

File "F:\env\chatbot\chatbotProj\chatbotProj\ChatbotCode\svm.py", line 31, in my_kernel
norm = LA.norm(X) * LA.norm(Y)

File "F:\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 2359, in norm
sqnorm = dot(x, x)

File "F:\env\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 478, in __mul__
raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')

ValueError: dimension mismatch
```

I'm new to python and this SVM area, does anybody know what's wrong or could recommend me how to write cosine similarity kernel better and cleaner?

Oh and, the dimension for the train X is (193, 634), train Y is (193, ), test X is (83, 634) and test Y is (83,) from `train_test_split` sklearn.

Answer (score 0):

Update : 
my friend told me it's happened because I have sparse matrix not a simple array, so I have to dense it and replace `my_kernel.py` code to be like this

```
def my_kernel(X, Y):
    X=np.array(X.todense())
    Y=np.array(Y.todense())
    norm = LA.norm(X) * LA.norm(Y)
    return np.dot(X, Y.T)/norm
```